# Rails select only the first entry in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to populate jquery jstree from an ancestry gem table. I'm using jbuilder to create the json input for jstree.

jstree requires the json data start with a [

So, I'm using

```
json.array!(@locations) do |location|
```

But, I'm looping through the children, so I only need the first location in the array.  I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
json.array!(@locations).first(1) do |location|
  json.label location.name
  json.children location.children do |child|
    json.label child.name
```

UPDATE

This didn't work either:

```
json.array!(@locations.first) do |location|
```

UDPATE2

This works except it starts with a { and it must start with [

That's why I was trying array.  How can I fix it?

(I know I need to work on the looping logic also)

```
json.id @location.id
json.label @location.name
json.children @location.children do |child|
 json.id child.id
 json.label child.name
 json.children child.children do |child2|
   json.id child2.id
   json.label child2.name
   json.children child2.children do |child3|
     json.id child3.id
     json.label child3.name
   end
 end
end
```

The results are:

```
{
   id: 1,
   label: "First in Tree"
  - children: [
    - {
        id: 2,
        label: "Child of 1"
```

...

Comment: Drop the block syntax. You can't iterate over one object.

Comment: meager - I'm sort of new at this.  How would I drop the block syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The first location in the array would just be

```
location = json.array!(@locations).first
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestion in jbuilder and got "undefined method `key?' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x007fd828d1b660>"

Comment: @Reddirt What is your `json.array!(@locations)`? Can you do `json.array!(@locations).inspect` and paste it?